# C++ containers - list members if operator<< is defined for type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for.

I've defined a:

```
template<class T>
::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& stream,const container<T>& list);
```

which can just say "container of length" (or something)
and it'd be really nice if this could list the contents of the container, if

```
::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& stream, const T&);
```

was defined. It may not always be declared however. This is something that would be known at compile time (provided the compiler could see a declaration, user error could mean it is never included)

Can this be done?

This is most certainly a duplicate, I can't be the first to want to do this but I'm not sure what I'd be searching for.

Any means to do this would be appreciated.

**Note:**

I did think about using a trait but (to copy and paste my comment):

I

> s there a C++11 way? I thought about traits too but you can't give
>   `int` a trait, assuming false by default (unless a trait exists and is
>   true) is great, but you can't do primitive types, or types defined
>   from libraries, you can of course create an `operator<<` for them

**Example**

Imagine:

```
container<int> someints(10); /*10 ints*/
container<A> someAs(5); /*5 As*/
container<B> someBs(7); /*7 Bs*/
```

With:

```
/*Obviously << for ints is defined*/

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const B& b) {
    stream<<"Whatever a B wants to do";
    return stream;
}

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const container<T>& list) {
    stream<<"A list of length "<<list.get_length();
    /*magic - if there is a << for T*/
    stream<<"\n";
    for(int k=0;k!=list.get_length();k++) {
        stream<<list[k]<<"\n";
    }
    /*end of magic*/
    return stream;
}
```

Then:

```
cout<<someints; /*shows a list of ints*/
cout<<someAs; /*shows its a list of 5 things - but cannot list the contents obviously*/
cout<<someBs; /*Showws it's a list of 7 things - and like someints lists them*/
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: You want to use an insert operator for a container who's length is a certain size? Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: WTF! No! If a I try to << a container I want it to show something like "Container for "(type id stuff)" of length "whatever. BUT if the thing it is a container of has a << I want it to list it, so: "container for type of length whatever:\n"[list of things in the container] @0x499602D2

Comment: Alright just trying to make sure. I had a hard time understanding is all.

Comment: @0x499602D2 added an example

Comment: What's confusing you @DieterLücking Nevin's answer is basically perfect, just that it requires boost. What part of if `operator<<` exists for what the container is a container for exists, show a list of the container's contents is hard? Not everything will have an `operator<<` and thus these cannot be put into an ostream, a container of such a type therefore can do no more than state it's length, it cannot state the contents.

Comment: This has been a vote roller coaster. No idea why, but I got my answer (Thanks to Dietmar) and that's what matters :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Boost has a type trait for that.  More details at [has_left_shift](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_left_shift.html).

Here is an outline of how to do it:

```
template<typename T>
struct Container
{
    void out(std::ostream& os, boost::true_type) const
    { os << "Huzzah"; }

    void out(std::ostream& os, boost::false_type) const
    { os << "Oops"; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Container const& that)
    {   
        using ostreamable = boost::has_left_shift<std::ostream, T>; 
        static_assert(ostreamable::value, "Not streamable");
        that.out(os, ostreamable());
        return os; 
    }   
};
```

The `static_assert` will make it so you cannot stream out the `container` if `T` is not streamable; remove it if you want to do something else at run time for a non-streamable `T`.

Comment: Is there a C++11 way? I thought about traits too but you can't give `int` a trait, assuming false by default (unless a trait exists and is true) is great, but you can't do primitive types, or types defined from libraries, you can of course create an `operator<<` for them

Comment: Why can't you specialize a trait for an int? Also, what if the trait just Sfinaes on the result of `declval<basic_ostream<X...>>() << declval<T>()` ? Because, TTBOMK that's precisely what such a trait would be.

Comment: I don't quite follow @sehe if you could put that in an answer - and not use boost - that'd be great!

Comment: @AlecTeal You should probably have noticed Dietmar's answer. Which is **exactly** this. :)

Answer (score 14):

This can be done: you'd use `std::enable_if<...>` to choose which version of the code should be used based on a predicate using the output operator. Below is a demonstration doing just that. The feature test is a bit ugly but right now I don't see how to really improve it. See [here](http://ideone.com/zNNPg9) for a live example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct container
{
    container(T const& v): value(v) {}
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
struct has_output_test {
    template <typename S>
    static std::true_type test(typename std::decay<decltype(
        std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<S>())>::type*);
    template <typename S>
    static std::false_type test(void*, ...);
};

template <typename T>
struct has_output
    : decltype(has_output_test<T>::template test<T>(
                    static_cast<std::ostream*>(0)))
{
};

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<has_output<T>::value, std::ostream&>::type
operator << (std::ostream& out, container<T> const& c)
{
    return out << "container[" << c.value << "]";
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!has_output<T>::value, std::ostream&>::type
operator << (std::ostream& out, container<T> const&)
{
    return out << "container[unknown]";
}

struct foo {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "foo=" << container<foo>(foo()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "int=" << container<int>(int()) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This just shifts the problem inside the container class.

Comment: @AlecTeal: What do you mean? If there is an output operator defined for `T` it will be used by `container<T>`'s output operator. That is, it does exactly what you describe it should do. Did you try the code...?

Comment: ... and I'd be interested in the reasons for the downvote (whoever voted the answer down).

Comment: Why not just a SFINAE on the return type w/o the class template? Something like `auto operator << (std::ostream& out, container<T> const& c)
-> decltype( out << c.value, std::declval<std::ostream&>() );` -- the `, declval` part might even be considered redundant.  (didn't downvote)

Comment: @dyp: Because there should be a different overload in case the operation isn't defined. Your technique works to hoist the output operator to containers of types which have an output operator but containers of types which don't wouldn't support an output operator at all.

Comment: I downvoted, nothing is missing but this should be below Nevin's answer, because that answer is much nearer to answering my question than this.

Comment: @AlecTeal: just to understand what you are saying: you downvoted my C++11 solution because you asked for a C++11 solution and the Boost solution is closer to what you asked for? Not to mention that my answer does answer _exactly_ what I asked for! Well, whatever. I shall keep that in mind.

Comment: @AlecTeal that's not how voting works. Ordering of posts is user preference anyway! You "accept" the answer that helps you the most. See: **[How Does Accepting An Answer Work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**

Comment: Well the `c.value` has confused me a bit, it seems to have put the ball for outputting entirely into the container's court - this is what I wanted to prevent. If my downvote is wrong (and it could be because I can't confidently read what you have done) please flesh it out a bit.

Comment: @Alec: If you look at my "container" implementation, you see that it contains _exactly_ one element: `value`. That is `c.value` merely access the one element in the container. If it were an actual value, you'd rather write the sequence from `c.begin()` to `c.end()` but since the container implementation wasn't the question I choose to use a simple one! However, yes, it is the container's responsibility to call the output operator of each element. The output of the elements will be done by the type's output operator, though.

Comment: @AlecTeal: Post order is supposed to be determined by a combination of *everybody*'s opinions, not yours alone. :-)

Comment: @DietmarKühl Oh, I see. However, this can be fixed with one more layer of abstraction I think ;) [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0cf091036410567)

Comment: Oh right, I wondered where you'd pulled the unknown from! That makes more sense, let me test this. @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... wtf does that mean? Everyone must vote the same else the one who doesn't is alone? - How very .... Soviet.

Comment: @dyp: agreed - that's simpler! I'd vote for an answer with that solution!

Comment: Also, this solved my problem. I would have accepted it if I didn't love going against the grain so much :P Thanks Dietmar.

Comment: @AlecTeal I actually appreciate this in some strange way. I guess the fact that you give credit where due trumps the incidental mechanics of the site. It's about ... humans with feelings after all :/

Comment: @sehe I can't tell if that was sarcasm or not. ...buuut... yes, I am thankful and appreciative of what Dietmar did. He has tonnes of rep and what I could give him is less than a 10th of a percent, he could add any bounty he wanted and is clearly here to help. Nevin has less than 1000, the 25 I have given him is more than 2.5% of what he has, it can go towards bounties he can't afford or open up various things this site has. FOR BONUSPOINTS it's a middle finger to some, like those who (probably) downvoted the question because of this comment thread and those who took -2 of the arbitrary stuff:p

Comment: I just appreciated your comment. I thought that was clear. As to your reasoning: I can only repeat that's not how voting works. [You may search for 'strategical voting', 'political voting' or whatnot on Meta. The quality of content is key here. Quality content comes **only** with recognition.]

Comment: So.... this way, I got to show I was grateful (beyond the inorganic tick) and help someone who actually gave a fairly useful answer, usually I upvote for the very mention of Boost because boot rules.

Comment: @AlecTeal About the "middle finger", that's not very helpful. I just upvoted both answers and the question. And yeah, I'm appalled at people who downvote a question for political reasons just as much as people who downvote answers for extraneous reasons. I'm sad that happened. I know one person who did and have voiced this opinion immediately at 9:14PM CEST. Let's hope it helps/helped :)

Comment: @DietmarKühl Well it's simpler *if you only ever need one of those functions*. Your way of writing the trait is not *much* more complicated, so the bit extra complexity pays off quickly. (With `enable_if_t` maybe as an extra defaulted template argument the trait might also be as simple to use.)

Comment: @sehe I don't follow the last bit, voiced it where? Also yes, the middle finger seemed like the right response after the pouring in of support that this answer got, and the several downvotes mine gained (3 up then suddenly 4 down!). Most answers don't get +7, not unless it's a popular question, which I doubt this was. It felt artificial. Anyway, ....

Comment: @AlecTeal I don't intend to tell you _where_ (although you should be able to figure it out). I just wanted you to know that I'm completely agreeing questions should _not_ be downvoted for any other reason than poor quality or poor fit. Now on your vote maths: you're misrepresenting history. You downvoted this answer at -1. I advertised it **after that fact**. Chances are without advertising this good answer, it would have stayed behind.

Comment: @sehe No no, I downvoted when it got +1, I wanted both to stay at 0 until the other had been developed (in response to my C++11 comment to it) and at the time I didn't think this answered my question but I wanted to hold back until I knew more - because my ignorance is not a reason to disapprove of something - I'm not religious :P It seems some other voter got in the mix, but I assure you I wanted to keep both of these at zero at the time. I'd rather upvote an answer with boost than downvote one that may be good (at the time I was unsure) if both achieve the same result. I'm a good person!

Comment: I grant you are most likely a good person. Reality is, you cannot control the votes. And you should not want to :) This causes pain and confusion, and it yields... what? Cheers, and happy codings in 2014!

Comment: @AlecTeal: `Everyone must vote the same else the one who doesn't is alone? - How very .... Soviet.` No idea where you pulled that from. Post ordering is based on taking the sum of everybody's opinion and sorting on the result, which is indicated by a vote, which is your statement on how good a post is. So you can downvote, but a downvote is supposed to mean that you think there is something wrong with the answer. The relative ordering isn't up to one individual: that would be a dictatorship! A system where all people "compete" to get posts in the exact place they want it could not work. :-)

Comment: "*my ignorance is not a reason to disapprove of something*" Erm, downvoting _is_ disapproving of something...

Comment: No idea why I downvoted this, please make an edit so I can change my vote.

Comment: @AlecTeal Your downvote is unlocked now. (I'd make a good janitor)